# Trying to do collisions between two different classes

Tags: class, processing, collision

Sorry I'm not posting my code in here but the format was screwing up and it wouldn't post properly. I'm trying to make a game in which the player controls a ship and asteroids move in from the right side of the screen and the player has to avoid them. For the life of me I can;t figure out how to get the asteroids to collide with the player causing the player to lose and could use some assistance.

[My Code for my game](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/628437)

Comment: Have it so when the asteroids move it checks if their X,Y values collide with the players X,Y values

Comment: Where should I put the collisions? I try to keep track of the ship position but it only tracks it without an error under the void display for the player ship, do i put the collisions in there?

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some research on [collision detection](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection). Get something simple working and post a [mcve] if you get stuck. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close.

In the function move() you calculate the new x and y position of the player:

```
  void move() {
    int r = d>>1;
    sx = constrain(sx + v*(int(isRight) - int(isLeft)), r, width  - r);
    sy = constrain(sy + v*(int(isDown)  - int(isUp)), r, height - r);
  }
```

Next you have you check if the player position is in the bounds of the asteroid.

This is from you code in the Display() function:

```
 void display() {
    image(ship, sx, sy, 100, 50);
    if (sx > a1x && sx < a1x && sy > a1y && sy < a1y){
      image(explo, sx, sy, 200, 200);
    }
```

This is in the right direction, but checks if both x and y of the player and the asteroid match **exactly**. This is very improbable, because it is the exact corner of both the player and the asteroid. Besides, the player might move more than 1 pixel per frame, causing it to skip the trigger.

Instead try this:
`if (sx > a1x && sx < a1x +asteroid.aw && sy > a1y && sy < a1y+asteroid.ah)`

This will check if the player x/y is in the bounds of the asteroid. And should get the result you want. However, this does not yet account for the height/width of the player spaceship. So you should also check
`if (sx+player.width > a1x && sx+player.width< a1x +asteroid.aw && sy+player.height> a1y && sy+player.height< a1y+asteroid.ah)`

Lastly I would make a general comment on your code. There is a lot of repetition. I assume you're learning, so that's okay, but allow me to give you some pointers that will make writing code a lot simpler: using [ArrayLists](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) and extending the use of objects

```
ArrayList<Asteroid> List_Of_Asteroids = new ArrayList<Asteroid>();
List_Of_Asteroids.add(new Asteroid(random(X1,X2), random(Y1,Y2))
```

This creates a list where you can add or delete asteroid objects. This makes it easy to do the same action for all asteroid, because you only have to type it once. Makes for less code as well. For instance:

```
player.move();
for (Asteroid rock : List_Of_Asteroids){
    if (player.collisionCheck(rock)){
        gameOver();  //triggers explosion image and subtracts life / ends game 
    }
}
display();
```

Just 5 lines to check all asteroids, even if there are 100. Everything that has to do with objects should be written in the object themselves. In your code the x/y position of the asteroids are kept in the main loop. You can easily divert those to the objects. If you look at the two code fragments above, you can access the asteroid x/y like this (inside the player class):

```
boolean collisionCheck(Asteroid a){
    if (x > a.ax && x < a.ax+a.aw && y > a.ay && y < a.ay+a.ah){
       return true;
    else{
       return false;}
```

Hope it helps!